# Erro ao enviar grande volume de e-mail com conta do GMail e PHPMailer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Temos um script para envio de e-mails, que pode ser poucos ou muitos, depende da necessidade do pessoal do nosso `RH`, não estou conseguindo resolver o problema e tratar de forma satisfatória a mensagem de erro que está sendo apresentada e nem exatamente como o fazer de forma correta, temos uma conta autenticada para o envio, o que acontece exatamente é que em determinado momento o envio acusa erro e não sei se os envios foram executados e nem como reverter os que teoricamente foram enviados, claro, se for possível.

O script que pega os `checks` marcados :

```
        function EnviaEmail() {
        var ntextoEmail = $('textarea[name="textoEmail"]').val();
        var nChecked = new Array();
        nChecked.push(<?php echo $id; ?>);
        $("#email .modal-body p").html('<img src="../images/loading.gif" alt="Enviando..." />');
        $("#email #btnEnviaEmail").hide();
        var params = {  
            list: nChecked,
            textoEmail: ntextoEmail
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "enviaEmail.php",
            data: params,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        })
        .done(function( json ) {
            console.log(json);
            if (json.flag == 1) {
                var msg = '<div class="alert alert-success" style="width:450px;">' + json.msg + '</div>' ;
            } else {
                var msg = '<div class="alert alert-error" style="width:450px;">' + json.msg + '</div>' ;    
            }
            $("#email .modal-body p").html(msg);
         })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            console.log( "Requisicao falhou: " + err );
            var msg = '<div class="alert alert-error" style="width:450px;">Falha na chamada. Tente novamente.</div>' ;
            $("#email .modal-body p").html(msg);
        });
    }
```

E o que está tentando enviar os e-mails:

```
    require_once('../../Connections/conCurriculo.php');

// Recebendo o array com os ID´S
$checkboxes = $_POST['list'];
// Codificando a string para resolver problema com acentuação
$textoEmail = utf8_decode(nl2br($_POST['textoEmail'])); 

$arr = array(); 
$arr['flag'] = 0;
$arr['msg'] = 'Erro na execução';

// laço para buscar e-mail e efetuar envio
foreach($checkboxes as $id) {

    // buscando informações do(s) candidato(s)
    mysql_select_db($database_conCurriculo, $conCurriculo);
    $query_rsRegistro = "SELECT * FROM candidato WHERE id_candidato = $id ";
    $rsRegistro = mysql_query($query_rsRegistro, $conCurriculo) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro);
    $totalRows_rsRegistro = mysql_num_rows($rsRegistro);

    // dados do candidato
    $nome = $row_rsRegistro['nome'];
    $emailCandidato = $row_rsRegistro['email'];

    //Dados pessoais
    $emailDestinatario = addslashes("recrutamento@cocari.com.br");
    $mensagem = addslashes($textoEmail);
    $mensagem = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$mensagem);

    require_once('../../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Charset    = 'ISO-8859-1';   
    $mail->SetLanguage("br");   
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port       = 587;                   
    $mail->Username   = "usuario";
    $mail->Password   = "senha";

    $mail->AddAddress($emailCandidato, "Recrutamento");
    $mail->SetFrom($emailDestinatario,"Recrutamento");
    $mail->Subject = 'Agendamento de Entrevista - ' . $nome;
    $mail->MsgHTML($mensagem);      
    $status = $mail->Send();

} // fim do foreach

if ($status == 'TRUE') {
    $arr['msg'] = 'Os e-mails foram enviados corretamente ';        
    $arr['flag'] = 1;   
} else {
    $arr['msg'] = 'Os e-mails não puderam ser enviados, por favor, tente novamente';
    $arr['flag'] = 0;       
}

$arr = array_map('htmlentities',$arr);
echo json_encode($arr);     

//Limpa os destinatários
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```

O erro que é exibido cai nessa parte do script:

```
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Requisicao falhou: " + err );
        var msg = '<div class="alert alert-error" style="width:450px;">Falha na chamada. Tente novamente.</div>' ;
        $("#email .modal-body p").html(msg);
    })
```

Poucos e-mails são enviados.

Comment: E qual é o "erro exibido"?

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, o erro exibido é esse: "Falha na chamada. Tente novamente."

Comment: Melhor seria a mensagem no `console.log`, visto que essa não te diz nada sobre o erro em si.